# Не могу установить innodb_buffer_pool_instances в Mariadb

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mariadb

Есть база данных Mariadb 10.5.8 на сервере Centos 7.8 c 32 GB RAM и i7-4770
Все таблицы в БД только типа InnoDB (таблиц MyISAM нет). Вот конфиг my.cnf:

```
max_connections = 1536
key_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer_size = 16M
join_buffer_size = 16M

# query_cache_size = 128M
# query_cache_limit = 2M
query_cache_size = 0
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_limit = 1M

tmp_table_size = 512M
max_heap_table_size = 512M

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 22G
innodb_log_file_size = 512M

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0

thread_cache_size = 512

table_definition_cache         = 1400     # As big as many tables you have
table_open_cache_instances     = 4

table_open_cache = 207000
open_files_limit = 207000
```

После перезагрузки все значения конфига устанавливаются корректно, кроме
`table_open_cache_instances     = 4`
Как я только не мучался с этой настройкой - устанавливал её вначале и конце конфига,
перезагружал как СУБД `systemctl restart mariadb.service` так и сервер целиком reboot. Ничего не помогает, после перезагрузки захожу в phpmyadmin, вбиваю запрос

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_instances'
```

и неизменно получаю

```
Variable_name                 Value
innodb_buffer_pool_instances  1
```

Долго гуглил, но так и не нашёл в чём может быть проблема. Она должна меняться, но не меняется. Может она зависит от какой-нибудь другой переменной и должна устанавливаться вместе с ней?

Answer (score 0):

> table_open_cache_instances

`table_open_cache_instances` в принципе не значится в [Full List of MariaDB Options, System and Status Variables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/full-list-of-mariadb-options-system-and-status-variables). Так что совершенно непонятно, что Вы пытаетесь установить.

> innodb_buffer_pool_instances

Эта установка *Deprecated and **ignored from MariaDB 10.5.1**, and removed in MariaDB 10.6.0*.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался в чём дело и где смотреть параметры. Что касается innodb_buffer_pool_instances - СУБД в логи написала, что [Warning] The parameter innodb_buffer_pool_instances is deprecated and has no effect. А касаемо table_open_cache_instances в логах вообще ничего небыло

Comment: Ещё вопрос, если параметра table_open_cache_instances не существует, то что тогда можно сделать при обнаружении в логах ошибок "Detected table cache mutex contention at instance 1: 42% waits. Additional table cache instance cannot be activated: consider raising table_open_cache_instances."